# discontinuity for $(x-1)\cdot{sgn(x^2-1)}$ sgn(t)=0 for t=0, $sgn(t)=\frac{t}{|t|}$ for $t\neq{0}$ in the reals

Tags: calculus

Consider $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with  $$f(x)= (x-1)\cdot{\operatorname{sgn}(x^2-1)}$$ where $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(t)=t/|t|$ for $t\neq{0}$. Where is $f$ discontinuous?

I know the answer is discontinuity at $x=-1$. I think there is no discontinuity at $x=1$. I do not know how to show it in this case. I know that generally for a discontinuity you can show using the definition of limits using epsilon and delta but in this case I do not know.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: By definition, continuity at $1$ is equivalent to $f(x) \to f(1)$ as $x \to 1$. Note that $x \to 1$ excludes $x = 1$, so you can simplify $f(x)$ in that case, because only one of the cases in the definition of $sgn$ would be relevant. But here we don't even need to care about that case because $sgn(x)$ is always between $-1$ and $1$ for any real $x$, so squeeze theorem would finish off the limit.

Comment: so there is discontinuity at $x=1$?

Comment: @cab: Do you know what is squeeze theorem?